# Is there a way in TypeScript to use element.hasAttribute() as a check without dummy variables?

Tags: typescript, dom, getattribute

In JS, I believe it is common to do the following to retrieve an element's attribute:

```js
let myAttr;
if (myElem.hasAttribute('my-attribute')) {
  myAttr = myElem.getAttribute('my-attribute');
}
```

However, due to TS only noticing that `hasAttribute` returns a boolean and `getAttribute` returns `string | null`, it doesn't realize that `myElem.hasAttribute('my-attribute')` is enough checking to guarantee that `myElem.getAttribute('my-attribute')` will return a string.

Is there a way to do this kind of check in TS, in a way that doesn't require dummy variables  (or get out of hand in the case of multiple attribute checks) like the following?

```
let myAttr: string;
let myAttr1 = myElem.getAttribute('my-attribute');
let myAttr2 = myElem.getAttribute('my-attribute-2');
if (typeof myAttr1 === 'string') myAttr = myAttr1;
else if (typeof myAttr2 === 'string') myAttr = myAttr2;
```

Comment: _”I believe it is common to do the following to retrieve an element's attribute”_ - My observation is the opposite: everyone just tests `getAttribute`‘s return-value for falsyness.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that would still require a dummy variable.

Comment: A dummy variable? What for?

Comment: If you do `if (typeof myElem.getAttribute('my-attribute') === 'string') myAttr = myElem.getAttribute('my-attribute')`, TypeScript would give the same error. I would have to do `let myAttr1 = myElem.getAttribute('my-attribute'); if (typeof myAttr1 === 'string') myAttr = myAttr1;`. Maybe I'm using the word "dummy variable" wrong but that's what I mean by it. It's very clunky.